# R: Which distribution to use with gbm for gamma distributed data?

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, boosting

When I use GLMs I can use the option `family="Gamma"` for analysing data consisting of positive real numbers. Also package `gbm` provides a large number of distributions to choose from, but there's none that matches the gamma distribution. Which distribution should I choose?

Comment: take the log of your data and use least squares (=logNormal) ?

Answer (score 6):

The distribution `gamma` are available in both `gbm` (only for the github version https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm , not in the CRAN version)  and `mboost` package.

For the package `gbm`, simply specify `distribution = 'gamma'` in the parameters of `gbm` function.

For the package `mboost`, use gamma distribution specifying `family = GammaReg()` in the options of the function `mboost` as shown in the toy example below :

```
library(mboost)
n.obs  <- 1000
n.iter <- 100
x1     <- rgamma(n.obs, shape = 1, scale = 1)
x2     <- rgamma(n.obs, shape = 2, scale = 1)
y      <- x1 + x2
model  <- mboost(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = data.frame(y, x1, x2),
                 baselearner = "btree", family = GammaReg(), 
                 control = boost_control(mstop = n.iter))
```

Comment: It's not too hard to add distributions to `gbm`.  We added `gamma` at work, and committed it: https://github.com/harrysouthworth/gbm/blob/master/src/gamma.cpp

Comment: Thank you for this precision. I have just edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: gamma is also available in the xgboost package.